# Exporting Unit Test To XML

Tags: xml, unit-testing, junit, xctest

I'm using the API OCUnit2JUnit (https://github.com/ciryon/OCUnit2JUnit) to output the results of my unit tests to xml into a folder. Seems like this OCUnit2JUnit framework is the easiest way to do that. I've installed ruby, done all of the setup, but when I run it, my "test-reports" folder is empty. This is the code I'm using:

```
xcodebuild test -scheme MySchemeName -sdk iphonesimulator7.1 -derivedDataPath "$(pwd)" 2>&1 | tee out.txt cat out.txt | ocunit2junit
```

Now, this creates a file in my project called out.txt and cat.txt which contains an enormous amount of info, but not in XML like it should be. My "test-reports" folder is still empty as well. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here, I've tried basically every variation of that code I could find on this website. I know that I'm building correctly, it's just when I add the good ol' | ocunit2junit it's not giving me an xml output of the results.

Does anyone have any ideas or a better way to output the results of an Xcode Unit Test to XML?